# PHP - check if database column is empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

How do I check if a database column is empty?

I tried the following:

```
$check = "SELECT Name FROM data";
$name = mysqli_query($con, $check);
if(is_null($name) == true){
   //run this code 
}
```

My method was to select the column "Name" and then checking if the column is return NULL or not. For some reason, the if statement runs when I put "is_null($name) == false" but my database definitely has no data in it so surely it should return true since it should be NULL. What am I doing wrong here?

How can I check if the column of a database is empty using if statement?

Thanks.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE YourColumn IS NOT NULL;

Comment: `mysqli_query` returns you a *result set* with all rows from your database. You will have to fetch rows one by one from it and inspect each row in turn; or perhaps you want to check whether any rows have been returned at all. But `$name` is *not* just "one column".

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use empty() function. change is_null to empty like this:

```
$check = "SELECT Name FROM data";
$name = mysqli_query($con, $check);
if(empty($name['Name'])){
   //run this code 
}
```

Comment: 1) This just checks whether the query has failed or not, it doesn't say anything about the contents of the result. 2) There's absolutely no need to suppress error reporting with `empty` here, you should use `!$name` for the same result.

Comment: \*facepalm emoji\*

Comment: Nope. Nope, it won't.

Answer (score 0):

you're treating the result as just the column.. it'd look more like

```
$check = "SELECT Name FROM data";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $check);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
if($row && $row["Name"] == null){
   //run this code 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$check = "SELECT Name FROM data";
$name = mysqli_query($con, $check);
$nameAssoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($name);
if(empty($NameAssoc['Name'])){
   //run this code 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can modify your mysql query , check if any column is empty or not.

```
$check = "SELECT count(*) FROM data where Name is not null and Name != '' ";
$name = mysqli_query($con, $check);
if($name > 0 ){
   //it means Name column is not null
}else{
// Name column is null
}
```